# Matching categories '\cX' and digit

Tags: regular-expressions

The regex info material suggests that `\\c6` should match digit characters.

In UTF-8 encoded buffers it doesn't; some of the other category letters work as expected (`l`, `|`, `a`).

Shouldn't `\\c6*` match `456` in `test456test`? What do I overlook, misunderstand?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It seems the main problem is that the ascii characters `0..9` aren't in the digit category, `C-u C-x =` shows `category: .:Base, a:ASCII, l:Latin, r:Roman` (it also has `general-category: Nd (Number, Decimal Digit)`, but apparently that's not what `\cC` looks for).

---

> Shouldn't `\\c6*` match `456` in `test456test`?

Also note that `\\c6*` matches the empty string.

```el
(let ((str "test456test"))
  (list (progn (string-match "[0-9]*" str) (match-string 0 str))
        (progn (string-match "[0-9]+" str) (match-string 0 str)))) ;=> ("" "456")
```

Comment: What is general category? I cannot find regex syntax to specify `Nd`. `[0-9]` what I used instead as `\c6` is not what it looks.

Comment: As far as I can tell, there isn't a regex syntax for `general-category`.